# Using shortcuts in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Using the following and pressing the tab key visual studio writes the properties for us.

```
//prop
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
//propg
public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
//propfull
private int myVar;

public int MyProperty
{
    get { return myVar; }
    set { myVar = value; }
}
```

As you can see all of them are int by default is there a way to change the shortcut to allow different data types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Visual Studio 2012 and all my C# code snippets under my

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\

folder. For example, when you edit `prop.snippet`, you will get like;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>prop</Title>
            <Shortcut>prop</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for an automatically implemented property
Language Version: C# 3.0 or higher</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>int</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>property</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>MyProperty</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[public $type$ $property$ { get; set; }$end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

As you can see, it is defined `<Default>int</Default>` as a default. You can change it which type as you want.

You can find them in [Code Snippet Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wy5tazc9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as well;

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I add multiple datatypes or is that not possible?

Comment: @Code I don't think it will be possible with multiple datatypes. Even it's possible, how compiler can know which type it choose?

Comment: Yes, that's true.. Thank you for your help